# How to import module properly in ionic?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

how to import angular page properly? i have home.ts with these property

```
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
```

here is my project look like :
[image]

Here is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { FirebaseAuth, AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    firelist: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
    chat:any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private af:AngularFire) {
        this.firelist = this.af.database.list('/chat',
        {
            query:{
                orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and then i have login.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FirebaseAuth, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import { HomePage } from './pages/home/home';


/*
  Generated class for the Login page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public nav: NavController, private auth: FirebaseAuth) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello LoginPage Page');
  }

  LoginGoogle(){
    this.auth.login({
        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
        method: AuthMethods.Redirect
    }).then((data)=>{
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
    })
  }

}
```

below is my project structure :
[image]

there where i need to add import my home page
which is looked like this `import { HomePage } from './pages/home/home';`

but i got error in my console that said

> "Error: Cannot find module "./pages/home/home""

how to import page properly?

Comment: Your login.ts file is under `src/pages/login`. So, if you want to import the home.ts which is in `src/pages/home/home`, you should import it from '../home/home'.

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül can you put it as an answer? what you said is true thank you

Comment: I added it as answer and tried to be more clear :)

Comment: For future questions: please don't post pictures of code. Instead post the actual code as text. That will make the code searchable and make it easier for us to use your code in an answer.

Comment: okay @FrankvanPuffelen i just think, i want to show the project structure too

Comment: Showing tje project structure is great. But the cost is that the text is now not searchable and can't be copy/pasted.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i get it, just updated my question, thank you :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the import path relative to the path of your file's path. In this case, to import `/src/pages/home/home.ts` in login.ts which is on `/src/pages/login`, you should import it like that:

```
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
```